# notify when the drop down menu change using jquery

Tags: jquery

So I use this to access my drop down menu but it doesnt work.

I am trying to  figure it out when the user change change there choice it should alert.
Could you please help me with this?

this is my html:

and my code is below:

```
function alert() {
    ('#pay select').change(function() {
        alert('change');
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have missed the `$`/`jQuery`:

```
    ('#pay select').change(function(){
//-^
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the *dollar sign* to show that you are calling jQuery. You probably also don't want to call it within a function - rather in the *ready* function in the head - something like this should work:

```
...

<head>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#pay select').change(function() {
         alert("Changed!");
      });
   });

...
```

Comment: Good point, but ready event is not fired within the head tag. You should use `$(document).ready(function({ // ...})`

Comment: You're completely right! My mistake, it's too early in the morning for me! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's 4.30 AM in my country :).